# Cypress conditional loop - Variable is not reached?

Tags: loops, cypress, do-while

I'm trying to create a custom method that will generate a string and put a condition ==> If the generated value is already in the database, we have to generate a new value. To simplify things, here's the code that will generate a random string and I manually change the result value for 'ABC' to make sure I'll reach the loop condition. The problem is once the "While" condition is called the 'clientValue' is empty. My variable "Let clientValue" seems to be unreachable.

```
it('test', () => {
        let clientValue = ''

        do {
            cy.getRandomString(3).then((response) => {
                clientValue = response;
                cy.log(clientValue)
                clientValue = 'ABC'; // I change the value here to make sure I get into the loop with the condition below
                cy.log(clientValue) // Print = ABC

            });
        }
        while (clientValue === 'ABC'); // Condition is never true because the 'clientValue' is empty at this stage
        cy.log(clientValue) // Print = Empty ??

    });
```

Comment: Where are you declaring `codevalue `?

Comment: @Sree.Bh Sorry my mistake. There's no "codeValue". It should be "clientValue". I corrected the post

Comment: cy commands are asynchronous and are queued to be run later, that's why the last log is printing empty.

Comment: Can you make `getRandomString(3)` as a normal 'helper' instead of a 'cy' custom command  if it's purpose is to generate a 'random' string only?

Comment: Hi @Sree.Bh, thanks for your response. What do you mean by a normal helper ?

Comment: I meant can it be considered a utility method which does not have any 'cy' commands? Secondly is it possible to move the 'do while' inside `getRandomString`?

Comment: Hi @Sree.Bh I created a new method (not cy command) with a return and it's working !!! Thanks you very much